# matrix from eigenvector formed basis

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Suppose $L: \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ is the linear transformation defined by $L\begin{pmatrix}
  a \\
  b \\
  c  \\
 \end{pmatrix}$=$A\begin{pmatrix}
  a \\
  b \\
  c  \\
 \end{pmatrix}$. Find $\mathscr{L}_{[B][B]}$ for $[B]=\left[\begin{pmatrix}
  -7 \\
  -3 \\
  5  \\
 \end{pmatrix}\right]$.

So $\mathscr{L}_{[B][B]}$ is a matrix but I only have one vector in my basis (i.e. [B]). So wouldn't $\mathscr{L}_{[B][B]}$ =\begin{pmatrix}
  -7 \\
  -3 \\
  5  \\
 \end{pmatrix}?

Comment: I'm really confused by your notation. What does $\mathscr{L}_{[B][B]}$ mean and how does it relate to $A$? What does $[B]$ mean? Just the vector $(-7,-3,-5)$? Or do the extra brackets mean something?

Comment: $\mathscr{L}_[B][B]$ is the matrix of our linear transformation, L, relative to [B] our basis. Bracket indicate bases and that the order in which a basis is stated matters. A is another matrix \begin{pmatrix}
  9 & -7 & 7 \\ 
  3 & -1 & 3 \\
  -5 & 5 & -3 \\
 \end{pmatrix}. The question explains their relationship as it was given to me. $(-7, -3, -5)$ is the basis I found when using eigenvalue $\lambda =1$

Comment: Well $B$ spans a subspace of dimension one only, so clearly $[B]$ is *not* a basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$...

Comment: ok so to find my basis $B$ of $\mathbb{R}^3$ consisting of eigenvectors of A I took my row reduced matrix of A and got $\begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 1& 2 \\
  0 & -5 & -3\\
  0 &0&0  \\
 \end{pmatrix}$ with all three rows equal to 0. And I am saying that $\begin{pmatrix}
  \alpha_1 \\
  \alpha_2 \\
\alpha_3  \\
 \end{pmatrix}$ is equal to A-1$\lambda$. Thus $\alpha_3$ can be any value, $-5\alpha_2-3\alpha_3=0$ and $\alpha_1+\alpha_2+2\alpha_3=0$. I let $\alpha_3 = 5$ thus $\alpha_2=-3$ and $\alpha_1=-7$

Comment: The question as you’ve stated it makes no sense since, as has been pointed out already, a single vector isn’t a basis for $\mathbb R^3$. You need to find a complete basis for the space.

Comment: So to add vectors to my basis, do I choose another value for $\alpha_3$ as in my comment above or am I just all wrong?

Comment: Choosing a different value for $\alpha_3$ will just get you a scalar multiple of the vector you already have, so that’s not the way to go. As you can see from the row-reduced matrix, this eigenspace is one-dimensional, so if you want to find a basis that consists of eigenvectors, you’re going to have to use a different eigenvalue.

Comment: I went and found two eigenvectors for eigenvalue 2. Now I have all three vectors. Do all three of them make a basis?